# how to display recording time while recording with NAudio?

Tags: c#, timer, naudio

i am trying to display the recording time while recording with NAudio Library Using C# windows Form Timer.This is the Code what i am trying to achieve.The problem i am having with this code is that timer's timing does not match with the length of recording.I want timer's timing and recording timing to be synchronized!

```
  private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        buttonStart.Enabled = false;
        buttonStop.Enabled = true;

        waveSource = new WaveIn();
        waveSource.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(44100, 2);

        waveSource.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<WaveInEventArgs>(waveSource_DataAvailable);
        waveSource.RecordingStopped += new EventHandler<StoppedEventArgs>(waveSource_RecordingStopped);

        waveFile = new WaveFileWriter(@"C:\one\Test0010.wav", waveSource.WaveFormat);
        waveSource.StartRecording();

      } 
  void waveSource_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
    {

        if (waveFile != null)
        {

            timerSoundRecord.Start();
            waveFile.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
            waveFile.Flush();
            var lenght = (int)(waveFile.Length / waveFile.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond);

            if (lenght == 6)
            {
                timerSoundRecord.Stop();
                waveSource.StopRecording();
                buttonStop.Enabled = false;
                buttonStart.Enabled = true;
            }



        }
    }

private void timerSoundRecord_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (progressBarRecordSound.Value != 6)
        {


            seconds = seconds + 1;

            labelTime.Text = @"00:0" + seconds;
            progressBarRecordSound.Value++;
        }
        else
        {
            timerSoundRecord.Stop();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You're updating seconds inside your timerSoundRecord_Tick at each tick. These are very different measurements.

Just make your length variable from the method waveSource_DataAvailable global and then check against it in timerSoundRecord_Tick, instead of using that variable seconds you're increasing.

```
  private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    buttonStart.Enabled = false;
    buttonStop.Enabled = true;

    waveSource = new WaveIn();
    waveSource.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(44100, 2);

    waveSource.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<WaveInEventArgs>(waveSource_DataAvailable);
    waveSource.RecordingStopped += new EventHandler<StoppedEventArgs>(waveSource_RecordingStopped);

    waveFile = new WaveFileWriter(@"C:\one\Test0010.wav", waveSource.WaveFormat);
    waveSource.StartRecording();
    timerSoundRecord.Start();
  } 

int length = 0;
void waveSource_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
{
    if (waveFile != null)
    {           
        waveFile.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
        waveFile.Flush();
        var lenght = (int)(waveFile.Length / waveFile.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond);

        if (lenght == 6)
        {
            timerSoundRecord.Stop();
            waveSource.StopRecording();
            labelTime.Text = @"00:0" + length;
            progressBarRecordSound.Value++;
            buttonStop.Enabled = false;
            buttonStart.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}

private void timerSoundRecord_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        labelTime.Text = @"00:0" + length;
        progressBarRecordSound.Value++;
}
```

Comment: Can you please add any example using stop watch? and how will display it with label i tried using time span but it didn't work ! thankyou

Comment: I figured you don't need a Stopwatch as you can get the elapsed time like you're doing with length inside the waveSource_DataAvailable method. I've edited my answer with new suggestion.

Comment: But when should i start timer? Before StartRecording method or in Data_Available Event?

Comment: it didn't worked ! :( length of recording is 6 seconds but timer shows 5 seconds !

Comment: Start it outside Data_Available Event, otherwise you keep starting it. Do it right before or right after starting to record, inside the button click.

Comment: That's because you stop it before it has the time to update the text label again with the latest result. Then call  labelTime.Text = @"00:0" + length and also progressBarRecordSound.Value++ inside the if (lenght == 6) condition. That should do the trick for the final second ;)

Comment: still not working !!! i think the basic reason behind this is that the timer is not synchronized with recording method !

Comment: Just included code. Is yours looking like this? What's going wrong?

Comment: Do you want to record exactly 6 seconds ? You cannot use a timer because you read chunks of audio data into a buffer (you dont know how big the chunks are), that why you need to calculate how much data theres in the buffer, `lenght = waveFile.Length / waveFile.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond`. You also do it the other way around, 6 seconds of recording is `var sixSecondBufferSizewaveFile.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond * 6`, then you can stop/trim the buffer.